# Lower bounds on the number of subgroups of a specific group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I am visiting this thread:

[$G$ is Abelian iff all the Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114865/g-is-abelian-iff-all-the-sylow-subgroups-of-g-are-normal)

I am wondering whether more can be said about the lower bounds of number of subgroups of $G$ when $G$ is of that order, which is $p_1 ^2 p_2 ^2 p_3 ^2 ... p_n ^2$, and it satisfies the said property, which is Abelian and/or having normal Sylow subgroups only. Maybe we can use the fact that Abelian groups are uniquely represented as direct product or something?

I know for a fact that exactly counting the number of subgroups of even an Abelian group is not easy, but this case seems like a special case to at least estimate how many subgroups $G$ at least has.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For any *abelian* group $G$ with $|G| = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$, where $p_1,\dots p_n$ are distinct primes, we have $G = P_1\times\cdots\times P_n$ with $|P_i| = p_i^{a_i}$. Thus, to count the number of subgroups of $G$, we only need to consider each $P_i$. You can have a try.

The "if and only if" statement holds only for $a_i\le 2$ for each $i$, because groups of order $p^2$ is abelian, but for $p^3$ we have two another non-abelian groups.

Comment: I see. If the Abelian property is removed but the cube-free order property stays, can something be said about the number of subgroups? I am looking to count subgroups or at least find a sufficiently strong lower bound but I have less encounter with subgroup counting.

Comment: Consider the simple case: $G$ is a non-abelian simple group if and only if  $G \cong \mathrm{PSL}(2, p)$ for a prime $p > 3$ with $p + 1$ and $p − 1$ cube-free. Even this case is not easy. If $G$ is of odd order, then it is solvable, this may help you: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/000298910x480847?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. And also http://users.monash.edu.au/~heikod/hddats/CubeFreeTh.pdf.@bms